# Proving the iff statement related to tree acyclicity

Tags: graph-theory

A graph is a tree if and only if its maximally acyclic . Is this statement true ?

> I can show the forward direction proof:

- The proof is as follows : as its a tree so its acyclic and connected , now if there were any path lets say u-v(length atleast greater than 1) as its connected so it has a path to it . So if we again make a edge connecting u and v it would make the graph to be having a cycle which is contradiction . I dont find the iff statement realted to this anywhere online so thought of better asking here .

Comment: In terms of proof style, try making your sentences more specific. The phrase "its connected so it has a path to it" has three instances of "it" referring to three different things, and only a mind-reader can know what you mean; also, you start talking about $u$ and $v$ without specifying what they are. A better phrasing of that sentence: "Let $u$ and $v$ be any two vertices with no edge between them. Because the tree is connected, there is a $u-v$ path, which must have length greater than $1$ because there's no edge directly from $u$ to $v$."

Comment: Similarly, being more specific and concrete lets you justify the claim "if we again make a edge connecting u and v it would make the graph to be having a cycle which is contradiction" without saying "well it makes sense in a picture". (Also, there's no contradiction here!) For example, you could say "Let $u, w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k, v$ be the path from $u$ to $v$. Then if we add the edge $uv$, the cycle $u, w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k, v, u$ is created. Since $u,v$ were two arbitrary non-adjacent vertices, a cycle is created whenever we add any edge, so the graph is maximally acyclic."

Comment: Yes you are right i should try to write a better style proof. Thanks for giving the tips for improving it :) @MishaLavrov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reverse direction, you have to show that a maximally acyclic graph has to be connected. In other words, we have to show that for any two vertices $u$ and $v$ in a maximally connected graph, there is a path between them. If $u$ and $v$ are already adjacent, then we have nothing to show. Otherwise, if we add the extra edge $(u, v)$ we will get a cycle, since the graph is maximally acyclic, which implies there was a path in the original graph between $u$ and $v$, which along with the newly added edge has resulted in the cycle.